# missing btime in /proc/stat how do i fix it?

Tags: command-line, ps, time

what does misning btime mean?

```
# ps aux | grep ssh
missing btime in /proc/stat
```

I'm on an embedded system (ts-7600)running a Debian version via UART.

```
#uname -a
Linux ts7600-4aa86d 2.6.35.3-571-gcca29a0+ #2 PREEMPT Thu Jan 22 12:21:50 PST 2015 armv5tejl GNU/Linux
```

I figured I should look at btime, and saw a post on a linux forum to do:

```
# cat /proc/stat␍␊
[21:14:57:236] cpu  3081 0 3263 217610 305 0 2 0 0 0␍␊
[21:14:57:236] cpu0 3081 0 3263 217610 305 0 2 0 0 0␍␊
[21:14:57:236] intr 307219 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 805 294809 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2525 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9034 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 24 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0␍␊
[21:14:57:293] ctxt 558977␍␊
[21:14:57:293] btime 0␍␊
[21:14:57:293] processes 2774␍␊
[21:14:57:293] procs_running 1␍␊
[21:14:57:293] procs_blocked 0␍␊
[21:14:57:293] softirq 37073 0 25258 1 695 0 0 634 0 564 9921␍␊
```

ok, so btime is 0, I also looked at time, and that is also zero.
do I need to fix this? I just want to make ssh work on this thing.
or how can I make time work? this device has an integrated RTC.

Comment: If it has an integrated RTC, then you need to find out why it is not using it correctly, if at all. Start with looking at the output of `dmesg` & ``lsmod`. You will need to know details of the RTC chip and whether its module has been configured to load.

Comment: Idk, maybe the battery is dead? is this a real problem or a nuisance problem? can I run ssh without an accurate clock? is ssh key-gen dependent on time at all?

Answer (score 0):

Ok well, I have a solution. (still confused about a variety of things, but I got the info I wanted out of `ps aux`)

I set the date with `date -s '2020-11-25 10:34:56'`
then ran

```
# ps aux | grep ssh
  root      2574  0.0  0.4   6252  1040 ?        Ss   12:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
  root      2663  0.0  0.2   2032   628 pts/0    S+   12:35   0:00 grep ssh
```

I mean I dont really care if the RTC is working, it just appears that the ps command needs a time to reference.  I mean, I could be way off on the explanation, but I got what I wanted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`ps` needs the btime to work out the proper start time of processes.  The process statistics give you the start time from when the system was booted (the btime) but this is meaningless to the current time.

I'm surprised that you get the message `missing btime in /proc/stat`. This happens when the `scanf("btime %lu")` fails to find a number, but 0 is a number.